# Accessing input to step function to then use as message for SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, aws-step-functions, serverless-framework-step-functions

I'm using the serverless framework to build a step function which receives input and then uses this input to send a message via SNS.

How do I pass the input to the message field?

Here is my definition and attempt:

```
stepFunctions:
  stateMachines:
    hellostepfunc1:
      name: testermachine
      definition:
        Comment: "test machine"
        StartAt: SNSState
        States:
          SNSState:
            Type: Task
            InputPath: $
            Resource: arn:aws:states:::sns:publish
            Parameters:
              TopicArn:
                Fn::GetAtt: [ MyTopic, TopicArn ]
              Message: {InputPath: $}
            End: true
```

Comment: Why not use the AWS SDK to build Lambda functions used in a Step Functions state machine. You have so much better control of the logic of the State machine and reading input values is so easy when writing your own code.

Comment: @smac2020 Yes, will likely use a lambda later but would like to just keep it as simple as possible right now and just use the json input as the SNS message if possible

Comment: With Code - you can easily read input to the Workflow like this:

String myCaseID = event.get("inputCaseID");

Then pass that value to a SNS service operation.

Comment: Okay i'll create a lambda and do it that way, cheers

Comment: Wrapping the AWS SDK within a Lambda function, you can perform any service operation in a Lambda function and perform custom logic. So many possibilites!

Comment: FRom the docs - "AWS SDK integrations work exactly like a standard API call using the AWS SDK. They provide the ability to call over nine thousand APIs across the more than two hundred AWS services directly from your state machine definition"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform a SNS publish operation within a Step Function. See [AWS Docs - Connect to SNS from Step Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-sns.html)

Comment: - Please try to explain as much as possible on the answer section, as the external link might become dead or its content moves other url, then would become hard for you to keep coming back and update your answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).